# VideoView Glitch while using Shared Element Transition

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-videoview, shared-element-transition

I've just finished implementing a transition featuring shared elements in **Recyclerview** and **ViewPager**. It seems to work well until I add a **VideoView** in Viewpager.

I've made a video to demonstrate the glitch. **https://youtu.be/dLuyDSFufHo**

As you can see, all are fine when there is ImageView in ViewPager. But when there is a **VideoView**  some glitch while opening and closing the activity.

How do I fix this? If it could be related to the way I've set things up I'd be happy to share some code.